# How to find integral curves to a given system of ODEs?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

How to find integral curves to a given system of ODEs

$$ \frac{dx}{y+3z}=\frac{dy}{z+5x} = \frac{dz}{x+7y}. $$

I tried to find multipliers but did not succeed. Can someone help to find integral curves?

Comment: Why are you putting PDE and differential geometry tags on an ODE question? I certainly don't see a differential geometry problem underlying this.

Comment: @TedShifrin Actually the above system comes only from the first-order PDE, so that is why I put the tag PDE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your system is associated with the following matrix :

$$M=\begin{pmatrix} 0   &  1 &    3\\
     5  &   0 &    1\\
     1  &   7   &  0\end{pmatrix}$$

(up to an unimportant factor). Its eigenvalues have no simple expression.

Their numerical values are  : $\{5.7753, -2.8876 \pm 3.1647i\}$

The numerical values of corresponding eigenvectors are  :

$$\begin{pmatrix}      0.4623\\
   0.5241\\
   0.7153\end{pmatrix}, \ \ \begin{pmatrix}     -0.7994\\
  0.7868\\0\end{pmatrix}, \ \ \begin{pmatrix}   0.4808\\
   0.5451\\
    -1.4878\end{pmatrix}$$

I assume you can take it from here.

Here is a graphical representation of a hundred trajectories with random initial conditions (the little stars). The eigenvector associated with the first (real) eigenvalue is in red, the two others in green.

[image]